# How to slice through a sequence of digits in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, slice

I have an N length string of digits or a number. I then turn it into a list to iterate over the digits. I want to slice the list into 5 digit blocks that look like so:

```
N = '1234567890'

slice1 = '12345'
slice2 = '23456'
slice3 = '34567'
```

and so on...

I am having trouble finding code examples of this for python, specifically slicing and for loops. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: @wwii nah, OP isn't asking to split the string to even chucks, but there should be other dupes.

Comment: @wwii. No. Not at all

Comment: What you are lookingfor is called a "sliding window"

Comment: @Code-Apprentice There are some great solutions here, but this is basically what I was looking for. "Sliding/Rolling window"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to understand how each of the elements in N = '1234567890' is indexed. If you want to access `"1"`, you can use `N[0]`. `"2"` with `N[1]`. And so on till `N[9]` which equals to `"0"`.

Your goals is to create things like

```
slice1 = '12345' 
slice2 = '23456'
slice3 = '34567'
```

Let's take a look at `slice1` with both values and how to access then via `N`

```
'1'    '2'    '3'    '4'    '5'
N[0]   N[1]   N[2]   N[3]   N[4]
```

Now we turn to list slices. Given a list `l`. One can select a part of it by specifying the `start` and `end`, two indeces like `l[start:end]`.

Note that `l[start:end]` will select elements

```
l[start], l[start+1], ..., l[end-1]
```

Yes. `l[end]` is not selected. The selection will include the starting index but exclude the ending index.

Back to the `slice1` example, how do you select `'12345'`? From the discussion above, we know we want indeces from 0 to 4. Thus, we need to put `N[0:5]` because as mentioned, `N[5]` would not be included in this way.

Given this practice, you can now write a for loop to yield `slice1`, `slice2`, and `slice3` in a row.

We can do it like

```
gap = 5
slices = []
for i in range(3):
    slices[i] = N[i:i+gap]
# slices will be ["12345", "23456", "34567"]

# or 
slice1 = N[0:5]
slice2 = N[1:6]
slice3 = N[2:7]
```

We did it by defining a variable `gap`. There is always a gap of 5 between the starting index and the ending index because the slices we want are of length 5. With some more observation: if a starting index is `i` and then the ending index should be `i + gap`. We increment one at a time to get a new slice.

Note that I only introduce one way to do list slicing that matches your particular need in this example. You can find more usage in this question [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of using list comprehension.

```
N = '1234567890'

all_slices = [N[i:i+5] for i in range(len(N)-4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

```
n = '1234567890'
for i in range(len(n)):
   print(n[i:i+5])
```

this should do the trick. But I need to say that it is hard to believe you actually search the Internet because it is a frequently asked question...

**UPDATE**

if you want to use the different slices you can try this:

```
n = '1234567890'

ar= [None]*len(n)

for i in range(len(n)):
   if len(n[i:i+5]) == 5:
      ar[i] = n[i:i+5]
   else:
      del ar[i:-1]
      del ar[-1]
      break

for i in ar:
   print(i)
```

So what happens here is:

- You make an array that has the size of the string and fill them with None values
- You check if the remaining size of the string is 5 pieces long

  - if so you slice the string in pieces of 5 with [i:i+5] and do the check again for the next slices
  - if not you delete the remaining None values and break the loop

Comment: When searching for the terms "For loop/looping over/iterating over slices/arrays/lists" I was having a trouble find the term "sliding/rolling window" so that's when I deferred to this site for help. Thanks for the solution and explanation.

Comment: No problem :) Please accept answer if you find this answer to be the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can also try converting `N` to a list beforehand, and popping off the first character each iteration, until the list is less than length `5`. Then you could just take the first five characters each iteration.

Here is an example using [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

```
from collections import deque
from itertools import islice

N = '1234567890'
items = deque(N)
size = 5

result = []
while len(items) >= size:
    result.append("".join(islice(items, 0, size)))
    items.popleft()

print(result)
```

Which Outputs:

```
['12345', '23456', '34567', '45678', '56789', '67890']
```

**Note:** [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) was used here to slice the `deque` object. You could also use `list(items)[:5]`, but this creates an extra copy of the list everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `dict comprehension`:

```
N = '1234567890'
slices = {'slice'+str(i+1): N[i:i+5] for i in range(len(N)-4)}
```

Usage:

```
slice1 = slices['slice1']
slice2 = slices['slice2']
slice3 = slices['slice3']
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

**As simple as that:-**

```
from collections import deque
N = '1234567890'
m = deque(N)
for i in range(len(m)-4):
    print N[i:i+5]
#output as you expected
```